# How Would I Extract Just Xyz Values From A Section Of A File

Tags: vb.net, parsing, extract

I have an input file that looks like this:

```
ID= 57010101-1
X= 0.0005
Y= 0.0006
Z= 0.0000
Avg= -0.0058

ID= 57010101-2
X= 0.0005
Y= 0.0005
Z= -0.0001
Avg= -0.0057

ID= 57010101-3
X= 0.0005
Y= 0.0007
Z= -0.0001
Avg= -0.0056
C= -0.0031
```

I need to extract the xyz from the id.
I have been messing with this for a while now but i cannot get it to grab it from the specific id that i give it.
Any suggestions?
I am using vb.net

Comment: Do you want to load them all into memory, or just read from the file each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load the whole file into memory, I would recommend doing something along these lines.  First, create a class to store the data for each item in the file, for instance:

```
Public Class MyItem
    Public Id As String
    Public X As Decimal
    Public Y As Decimal
    Public Z As Decimal
    Public Avg As Decimal
    Public C As Decimal
End Class
```

For simplicity sake, I just made public fields for each datum, but they ought to be public properties, instead.  Next, create a method that loads the file into a list of those objects.  For instance, something like this would work:

```
Public Function LoadItems(ByVal filePath As String) As Dictionary(Of String, MyItem)
    Dim items As New Dictionary(Of String, MyItem)()
    Dim item As MyItem = New MyItem()
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
        Dim parts() As String = line.Split(New String() {"= "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If parts.Length = 2 Then
            Select Case parts(0)
                Case "ID"
                    item = New MyItem()
                    item.Id = parts(1)
                    items.Add(item.Id, item)
                Case "X"
                    item.X = Decimal.Parse(parts(1))
                Case "Y"
                    item.Y = Decimal.Parse(parts(1))
                Case "Z"
                    item.Z = Decimal.Parse(parts(1))
                Case "Avg"
                    item.Avg = Decimal.Parse(parts(1))
                Case "C"
                    item.C = Decimal.Parse(parts(1))
            End Select
        End If
    Next
    Return items
End Function
```

The example above returns the items in a dictionary using the ID as the key for each item.  Doing so makes it very quick and easy to access the objects in the list by their ID.  For instance:

```
Dim items As Dictionary(String, MyItem) = LoadItems("C:\Test.txt")
Dim item As MyItem = items("57010101-3")
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", item.X, item.Y, item.Z)
```

However, if you don't want to load the whole file into memory, you'd want to do something very similar, but rather than having the load method return a list of items, you'd want it to just return a single item.  Inside the load method, instead of loading all lines at once, you'd want to use a file stream to read a single line at a time, then immediately close the file and return the object once you find it.